# Path not found - GetOpenFilename VBA Error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm trying to build a sub that allows a user to attach an image to a user form, my approach is to use OpenFileName to get the file path of the chosen, and then copy it into another folder for that submission for later use. I keep on getting a path not found error each time I select an image. It gets thrown as soon as GetOpenFilename is executed. Why is this happening and is there a better way that I could be going a bout this? Thanks.

```
Private Sub AttachImagesButton_Click()
    
    Dim photoPath As Variant
    Dim newTicketFolderName, destination As String
   
    'get user to select a photo from disk and assign to
    photoPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Image Files (*.*), *.*", , "Select image")
   
    On Error GoTo Error
   
    If photoPath = False Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What is the specific error message? Where are the images stored (locally, network drive, etc.)?

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? What is this `On Error GoTo Error` supposed to do? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71415832/edit) at any time to add more detail.

Comment: @BigBen Ive only posted what is related to the GetOpenFilename as that's where my error is. When the line of code that calls it happens, I get my error. I'm trying to select a basic .jpg from my desktop

Comment: @VBasic2008 The rest of the code is not necessary in this example because the line that calls GetOpenFilename is what throws the error. The on error just shows a message box with err.descriiption

Comment: Not sure if this may help, but you have a space between the comma and the asterisk. Try without it. Also, you could try by omitting the first parameter: `...( , , "Select image")`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 unfortunately neither of those changes helped

Comment: The only other reason I can think of is if the file contains letters that are not part of the English alphabet. Definitely let us know what the reason was when you fix it.

Comment: Perhaps a sample filename (foo.jpg) would be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen the one im trying to use is just called image.jpg